# How to get a DOM element in Stenciljs?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

```
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';
@Component({
    tag: 'my-component',
    styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
    shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() last: string;
  getElementHere() {
     // how can I get the div here?
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello, World! I'm {this.first} {this.last}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to get the DOM element just like in native JS. How do you do this in Stencil? `getElementById` does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand on Fernando's answer, the `@Element` decorator binds the component's root element to this property. It's important to note a few properties of this approach:

1. The @Element bound property is only available after the component has been loaded (`componentDidLoad`).
2. Because the element is a standard HTMLElement, you can access elements *within* your current component using the standard `.querySelector(...)` or `.querySelectorAll(...)` methods to retrieve and manipulate them.

Here is an example showing when the element is accessible, and how to manipulate nodes within this element (correct as of stencil 0.7.24):

```
import { Component, Element } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent {

    @Element() private element: HTMLElement;
    private data: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
        console.log(this.element); // outputs undefined
    }

    // child elements will only exist once the component has finished loading
    componentDidLoad() {
        console.log(this.element); // outputs HTMLElement <my-component ...

        // loop over NodeList as per https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/
        const list = this.element.querySelectorAll('li.my-list');
        [].forEach.call(list, li => li.style.color = 'red');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="my-component">
                <ul class="my-list">
                    { this.data.map(count => <li>{count}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't get when shadow: true option is set.How to get value from a shadow element!?

Comment: @SuriyaKumar you mean it doesn't work in a scenario similar to above, but with `shadow: true` in the `@Component` decorator?

Comment: @SuriyaKumar can you share your code in a gist? or perhaps open a new SO question?

Comment: Note that the `componentDidLoad` restriction is not true (perhaps it was true in older versions of StencilJS). The host element defined using `@Element` is available from `componentWillLoad`. Other DOM elements in the template defined using `ref` are only available after the component has loaded i.e. `componentDidLoad`.

Comment: @SuriyaKumar in case of `shadow: true` you have to access the shadow DOM through `this.element.shadowRoot`: https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling#things-to-remember-with-shadow-dom

Comment: BTW, why not add the extra info to Frenando's response, rather than add an new post to provide more details for the same solution?

Comment: @Squiggle PLEASE add what SuriyaKumar and G Tranter added so that you answer is complete

Answer (score 7):

[From the official docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#getting-a-reference-to-a-dom-element)

> In cases where you need to get a direct reference to an element, like you would normally do with document.querySelector, you might want to use a ref in JSX.

So in your case:

```
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';
@Component({
    tag: 'my-component',
    styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
    shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() last: string;

  divElement!: HTMLElement; // define a variable for html element

  getElementHere() {
    this.divElement  // this will refer to your <div> element
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={(el) => this.divElement= el as HTMLElement}> // add a ref here
        Hello, World! I'm {this.first} {this.last}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can get the current HTML element adding this into your component as property:

`@Element() myElement: HTMLElement;`

You can read more about this [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/decorators#element)

Hope this helps you :)